# ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination

Tags: excel, cell, autofill, vba

I am new to VB programming and to excel macro.
I record a macro with below code.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date today"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J922")
```

I want ("J2:J922") to be dynamic. Sometimes the column is not exactly J922. It can be below or above to the range.
Can anyone help me to what is the proper code for this?

Comment: You'd need to describe how the range to be filled would be determined

Answer (score 0):

You can use a power table hence you can simply mention the range as `Range("Table1[#Headers],[Headername]")`